# Auto Generated -Swift file not able to add <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, email, objective-c-swift-bridge

I am working on a project where the code is in Objective-C & Swift 3.2,

I am sending mail from Swift file where I need to extend MFMailViewControllerDelgate

but when I Build project I get an error

> Can not find protocol declaration for 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate'
>   at Swift Header file

in below code part

```
@interface EmailManager (SWIFT_EXTENSION("targetname")) 
   <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
   - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController * 
   _Nonnull)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
   error:(NSError * _Nullable)error;
@end
```

To resolve error I edit swift header file & add Manually `<MessageUI/MessageUI.h>`
And everything works fine.
but When new changes are made in Project or ad new Swift file this auto-generated file get reset & I get an error again.

please suggest some permanent solution

FYI:
In Auto generate file there is `@import MessageUI`
In Build Setting there is `MessageUI` in Framework
In Build Setting Define Modules set to YES
ignore target name in the code snippet

Comment: This looks like an Xcode bug to me. You can try enabling modules in your project, or adding `#import <MessageUI/Message.h>` to your `.pch` file. Enabling modules is the better fix if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I coudn't find answer so I did it in Objective C.